# Flutter device daemon where' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: flutter, android-studio, environment-variables

Flutter device daemon #1 exited (exit code 1), stderr: 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
I try to solve it by reinstall git or add path but doesn't success
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXT0c.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.